# Insert only when values does not exist in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, duplicates, sql-insert

I have below query which i am using oracle stored procedure. The query is running fine but i want to add condition in this query such that if the combination of row values with `name,e_id,c_date,p_check` already exist then do not insert this values.

```
INSERT INTO M_LOG(NAME, E_ID, C_DATE, STATUS, P_CHECK)
Select MAX(ML.NAME), ML.E_ID, C_DATE, 1, 'M Step_1' from F_LOG ML,DIR_LOG MD
WHERE ML.NAME != MD.NAME and ML.E_ID != MD.E_ID and MD.C_DATE = LAST_DAY(to_date(sysdate,'YYYYMMDD'))
GROUP BY ML.E_ID,C_DATE;
```

Comment: Use merge statement

Comment: Agree `merge` is more flexible, but you might also consider adding a `not exists (select ...)` to your existing `insert`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `MERGE` with a `WHEN NOT MATCHED` clause:

```
MERGE INTO M_LOG dst
USING (
  Select MAX(ML.NAME) AS name,
         ML.E_ID,
         C_DATE,
         1 AS status,
         'M Step_1 As p_check'
  from   F_LOG ML
         INNER JOIN DIR_LOG MD
         ON (   ML.NAME != MD.NAME
            AND ML.E_ID != MD.E_ID )
  WHERE  MD.C_DATE = LAST_DAY( TRUNC( sysdate ) )
  GROUP BY ML.E_ID,C_DATE
) src
ON (   src.name    = dst.name
   AND src.e_id    = dst.e_id
   AND src.c_date  = dst.c_date
   AND src.p_check = dst.p_check )
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (NAME, E_ID, C_DATE, STATUS, P_CHECK)
  VALUES ( src.name, src.e_id, src.c_date, src.status, src.p_check );
```

Comment: sure i will try this

Answer (score 1):

You could use `NOT EXISTS`.

```
 INSERT INTO m_log
            (
                name,
                e_id,
                c_date,
                status,
                p_check
            )
SELECT MAX(ml.name) name,
       ml.e_id,
       c_date,
       1          status,
       'M Step_1' p_check
FROM   f_log ml
WHERE  NOT EXISTS
       (
                SELECT   1
                FROM     dir_log md
                WHERE    ( ml.name = md.name
                               OR  ml.e_id = md.e_id )
                AND      md.c_date = LAST_DAY(TRUNC(SYSDATE)) )
                GROUP BY ml.e_id,
                         c_date;
```